# Parsing order for HTML and Javascript

Tags: parsing

Hello I have a question about the Parsing order for HTML and Javascript. On the code below, it seems to make sense that:

1. "Paragraph 1" would show up on the webpage first,
2. Receive the alert for "First Script Block"
3. "Paragraph 2" would show up on the webpage
4. Receive alert for "Second Script Block"

and so on..

```
<html>
<body bgColor = "WHITE">
  <p>Paragraph 1</p>
<script type = "text/javascript">
  // Script block 1
  alert("First Script Block");
</script>
  <p>Paragraph 2</p>
<script type = "text/javascript">
  // Script block 2
  document.bgColor = "Red";
  alert("Second Script Block");
</script>
<p>Paragraph 3</p>
</body>
</html>
```

But when I actually render it, the alert comes first and then shows the "Paragraph 1" after clicking the alert message.

Could someone help me why this is the case?

Thank you,

Comment: I believe this is implementation specific. You should use things like body.onLoad()

Comment: I agree with @JonathonReinhart there are browsers where js is executed when whole page loads, and there are ( probably ) those that execute it when it's loaded, and page doesn't have to be loaded..

Comment: You are right, perhaps its the browser settings. I will look further onto the onLoad() methods. I'm sorry for such a late reply, frankly I didn't think I'd receive any since I'm new here. Thank you for your kind comments.

Answer (score 0):

Add head empty tag. It fixed on my chrome browser.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body bgColor = "WHITE">
  <p>Paragraph 1</p>
<script type = "text/javascript">
  // Script block 1
  alert("First Script Block");
</script>
  <p>Paragraph 2</p>
<script type = "text/javascript">
  // Script block 2
  document.bgColor = "Red";
  alert("Second Script Block");
</script>
<p>Paragraph 3</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: And why should that be a *trustworthy* reason for the change in order?  If, as @JonathanReinhart explains, this behavior is browser specific, there is no a priori reason for adding a head tag to be a cure across all browsers.  Examples where it happens are not proof.

Comment: Yes i tried on my chrome browser, and its not the kind of result i had expected.